# Multiple jquery libs are not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show().click(function () {
    $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
<style>
.slidingDiv {
height:100px;
background-color: #DCFCF2;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #99FFFF;
width:400px;
}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Reply</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
<a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>
</body>
```

This code is working perfectly .. but when i m putting this code in another page n loading it through ajax, the jquery is not working.. I ve already one sliding div in my page & after checking another menu, i m using ajax there. but after the page got loaded, the jquery is not working. 
The jqueries i ve in my main page are

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help here ?? Thankss in advance ..

Comment: Any live example with your page loaded via ajax available ?

Comment: If you include a html fragment via ajax inside your main page, you need to include your javascript ( jquery ) files in main page only, not in both.

Comment: yes i ve done that .. but not working @franchez

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();// perhaps you want $(".show_hide").toggle(); here
$(".show_hide").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefaul();// you need preventDefault as you are clicking to a link
   $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code and its worked.

check it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/Q6k95/

you cant use $(this).next(); because used to different area your click class. And its dont know where is next element??

edit your jquery like this :

```
$(".show_hide").click(function () {
 $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: did u get wat i want to do ??